# Что такое python egg

Tags: python

Я новичок в программировании и изучаю python. Прошу *кратко* и *доступно* объяснить **python egg**!

Comment: Самая первая ссылка из гугла ведь: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2051192/10941639.

Comment: Так-то тут не нашел вопроса/ответа про egg. Поэтому, не думаю, что обязательно закрывать вопрос и тем более минусовать автора. Мб кто-нибудь подготовит ответ? :) Можно сделать перевод из ссылки в комментарии выше